# How can I use ViewModel in custom helper class?

Tags: android, mvvm

I make Retrofit API call using ViewModel & LiveData.

```
public LiveData<List<History>> getHistory(Context context, String queryType, long from, long to) {
        
    return HistoryDataRepository.getInstance(context).getLocationHistory(queryType, from, to);
    
}
```

And I'm using this function in my Fragment like this:

```
viewModel.getHistory(requireContext(), ConstantsHelper.QUERY_TYPE, fromDate, toDate).observe(this, data -> {
..
..
..
}
```

I want to create a HistoryHelper class and move this function to my helper class to make my code more organized.

How can I use ViewModel functions in my custom helper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to do something like this, try changing the arch. Not very helpfull from the question to suggest one. but,
You can implement a listener inside your Helper class which would get the ViewModelStoreOwner.

```
HistoryHelperListener{
   fun getViewModelStoreOwner(): FragmentActivity
}
```

Then using `getViewModelStoreOwner()` you can init your viewModel

```
private var viewModel: TransactionTagHandlerViewModel? =
    ViewModelProvider(
        listener.getViewModelStoreOwner(), object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return HistoryHelperVM() as T
            }
        }
    )[HistoryHelperVM::class.java]
```

PS: Handling LiveData inside custom class could be an overhead so would prefer using interface for the API callbacks & handling states in `HistoryHelper`

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels are scoped to the lifecycle of where they are used: Activity or Fragment. Unless the helper class you want to create is one of those it's not feasible to use a ViewModel within it. See [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and the [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#fetching_data) for more details.

The repository is already your 'helper' class, handling the business logic of managing data in your app.

One thing I noticed is that queryType is always the same, so you can probably remove that as a parameter. Also, why does your repository need a Context?